# How to make any android application for use in different devices as aspect of UI

Tags: android

As i am a new to android and made a small application but that doesn't give same
appearance on different devices
Thanks

Comment: Thanks all,

  I got the answer........ as android supports different density and different dpi images need is just put them in your folder where images are.rest it will detect automatically in runtime to complete your UI with best configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Relative layout. Refer these links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading tutorial on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use different ressources and layouts for various screen sizes and orientations.
You can find an extensive explanation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout and images of high density.